# How to change text transparency in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm very new to HTML/CSS and I'm trying to display some text as like 50% transparent.  So far I have the HTML to display the text with full opacity

```
<html><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"4\">THIS IS MY TEXT</font></html>
```

However, I'm not sure how to change its opacity. I've tried looking online, but I'm not sure exactly what to do with the code I find.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

`opacity` applies to the whole element, so if you have a background, border or other effects on that element, those will also become transparent. If you *only* want the text to be transparent, use `rgba`.

```css
#foo {
    color: #000; /* Fallback for older browsers */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Also, steer far, far away from `<font>`. We have CSS for that now.

Comment: A far superior solution compared to the accepted answer, IMO. You do not need to add an additional span element to the HTML to apply opacity solely to the text.

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: what browsers are "old" in this sense?

Comment: @RickDavies According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors), IE9 or higher is required. If you need to support IE8, you still need the fallback. Otherwise, you should be fine with just `rgba`.

Comment: Hmmmm, neither is the opacity property. Wow.

Comment: It works here on this site when I do it via inspector, but not on my local test site. Weird. And the property isn't overriden. Whaaaaaaaaat.

Comment: Wait, it's because opacity isn't allowed on the `:visited` pseudo class? What?!? I never knew. I think that's lame.

Comment: @trusktr Modern browsers place those limits to protect the user's privacy, [see MDN for an explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector). You can still use `rgba` for `:visited` rules but you can only change the red, green and blue components. The alpha component is always taken from the *non-visited* style. (Also, your comment is a bit off-topic. It might be better as a separate question, and it would also be more visible to other answerers.)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I found that article, but I think that rather than preventing us from styling :visited, a better approach would be to prevent getComputedStyles() from returning any meaningful information information thieves. Then we could style to our heart's content.

Comment: this does not worked for me, while setting `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)` on a `<div>` element. the reason was that for body{} was also a color set which then was displayed instead the color of the <div>. removing the color definition in body{} worked in the end.

Comment: Just a note: this solution changes not only opacity but the color as well.

Comment: @vchrizz To override previously set rule use " !important" keyword. example: `color: rgba( 0, 255, 0, 0.5) !important`

Answer (score 119):

Check [Opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp), You can set this css property to the div, the `<p>` or using `<span>` you want to make transparent

And by the way, the font tag is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp), use css to style the text

```
div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Edit: This code will make the whole element transparent, if you want to make ** just the text ** transparent check @Mattias Buelens answer

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Its code makes entire element (div) translucent. The Question specified only the text. The higher-voted [sibling answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10835846/642706) should be the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me hiding a text in my wordpress template. Instead of (opacity: 0.5;) I just used (opacity:0;).

Comment: @BasilBourque you're absolutely right however, selector targeting makes this answer valid. example: h1 {opacity: 0.5;}

Comment: An advantage of this answer is that, if the element has only text in it (you can add a span for that purpose if it isn't already the case), then you don't need to know the current color to set the opacity. The answer linked by Basil requires overriding the color values. If you later change the general theme of the site, e.g. from light to dark, you need to remember to also change `color: rgb(x,y,z,0.5)`, whereas `opacity: 0.5` is color-independent. (One can argue it's technically incorrect, and that's not wrong, but I find this the easiest and most maintainable solution.)

Answer (score 20):

Just use the `rgba` tag as your text color. You could use `opacity`, but that would affect the whole element, not just the text. Say you have a border, it would make that transparent as well.

```
.text
    {
        font-family: Garamond, serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Your best solution is to look at the "opacity" tag of an element.

For example:

```
.image
{
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

So in your case it should look something like :

```
<html><span style="opacity: 0.5;"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"4\">THIS IS MY TEXT</font></html>
```

However don't forget the  tag isn't supported in HTML5.

You should use a CSS too :)

Answer (score 7):

What about the css `opacity` attribute? `0` to `1` values.

But then you probably need to use a more explicit dom element than "font". For instance:

```
<html><body><span style=\"opacity: 0.5;\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"4\">THIS IS MY TEXT</font></span></body></html>
```

As an additional information I would of course suggest you use CSS declarations outside of your html elements, but as well try to use the font css style instead of the font html tag.

For cross browser css3 styles generator, have a look at http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 5):

## [color-mix](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors)

*[(see support table)](https://caniuse.com/?search=color-mix)*

`color-mix` can be used to mix `currentColor` with other colors (like `transparent`):

```css
html {
  font: 700 2em Arial;
  color: red;
}

p:first-of-type {
  /* 50% opacity of currentColor which derrives from the inherited color property */
  color: color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 50%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<p>Text with color opacity</p>
<p>Normal text color</p>
```

## [Relative color syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors)

With this new CSS ability (*css-color-5*) which allows color format transformations, it also will also allow adding opacity to any color in any format, for example, to `RGB` (relative transformations can be done to any other format):

```css
 /* assume some sort of a base color variable */
html { --color: red; }

/* convert the color variable to RGB+A */
p { color: rgb(from var(--color) r g b / 50%) }
```

```html
<p>Text with opacity</p>
```

---

*<del>(As of writing, not yet available in browsers. Will update once arrives)</del> - Working with limitation: still cannot use `currentColor` as the base color ([see tests](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors))*

Answer (score 4):

Easy! after your:

```html
<font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"4\">
```

add this one:

```html
<font style="opacity:.6">
```

you just have to change the ".6" for a decimal number between 1 and 0

Answer (score 4):

There is no [CSS](http://www.themexpro.com/) property like background-opacity that you can use only for changing the opacity or transparency of an element's background without affecting the child elements, on the other hand if you will try to use the CSS opacity property it will not only changes the opacity of background but changes the opacity of all the child elements as well.
In such situation you can use RGBA color introduced in CSS3 that includes alpha transparency as part of the color value. Using RGBA color you can set the color of the background as well as its transparency.

Answer (score 3):

try to play around with `mix-blend-mode: multiply;`

```
color: white;
background: black;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs34f9FiHps&t=74s)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `opacity` to a element, entire element effect that(background+other things in it),you can use `mix-blend-mode` to the CSS attributes of the specific element,

Refer these sites:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old and answered thread, but it's the first result I got in google when searching for changing text opacity, so I will add my solution here for anyone else looking for this.

The answers here were not exactly satisfactory to me, using `rgba` was not an option for me, I wanted the color of the text to be defined as a css variable, and alter it's opacity without changin the background opacity so `opacity` property was not an option either.

However, I've figured out that there's a trick you can use with the new [color-mix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) property. Simply mix the current text color with a completely transparent one and the mixing ration becomes the new color opacity:

```css
:root {
 --text-color: #fcba03;
}

.example {
  color: var(--text-color);
  background: black;
  padding: 24px;
}

.opaque-text {
  color: color-mix(in srgb, var(--text-color) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <span>
    Regular Text
  </span>
  <br />
  <span class="opaque-text">
    Opaque Text
  </span>
</div>
```

This can also be used with the `currentColor` instead of `var(--text-color)`.