# transparent text in text box (css, js, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to implement the following styling of textboxes:
 - the font color should be #555555, but it needs to be greyed out at 50% opacity.
 - color for background should be #c5eafb.
Browsers: IE8/9, latest FireFox.

**Update**

There are examples on how to implement transparent background. But this is not exacly what I need.

My aim is to have transparent (50%) font color with opaque background.

The only possible way I've found is using RGBA ([How to change text transparency in html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css)).

```
<table>
  <tr class="fontTable">
     <td class="rowHeight">Parameters</td>
     <td class="alignRight">
       <label>Name</label>
       <label>
         <input type="text" class="inputDisabled" value="" size="15"/>
       </label>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>

.inputDisabled
{
  border-color: #a0c5d6;
  background-color: #c5eafb;
  color: #000; /* Fallback for older browsers */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

This works fine in FF and IE9, but not supported in IE8.

How can this be implemented for IE8 also?

Comment: Use an RGBA value for your text color?

Answer (score -2):

For your textarea I suggest you use

```
textarea {
  background:#c5eafb;
  color: rgba(85,85,85,0.5);
}
```

Comment: rgba colors are not supported in IE8 (and OP says he needs IE8 support). source: http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba