# opaque text with colored background - CSS only

Tags: html, css, opacity, transparent

Is it possible for a div to have opaque/transparent text with a white background. (div1(+)

Basically where I can have another colored DIV (div2) behind the first div(div1) And the text will be the color of the div behind it (div2) purely through CSS without JS?.

Comment: may be refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css

Comment: do you want cut-out text? basically you see the background of the underlying div through the letters of the text on the top div? like this https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? (read answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-with-white-background-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, what you want to do is use the text punch through the first div and display the color or image from the second div behind it.

There is no way of doing this with CSS only. (At least to this day)

I think you might find this useful.

http://blog.ericzhang.com/punch-through-text-masks-with-css-and-html5/

Comment: Yes something like this. So not possible purely with CSS? Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```css
p{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Or like this?

```css
p{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

or like this?

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  font-size: 30px;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asked. He want a text in a plain color background to be trasparent so you can see what is behind the plain color through the text

Comment: Whatever he wants, he can achieve this by `rgba` or `opacity`. I don't think so that this can be done by any other method.

Comment: Yes I want say color:opacity() so only the text is transparent but not the entire div. therefore i can see through only the text, but the rest of the div is a solid color.