# How to substract text color from a background using css or js

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve this http://prntscr.com/b912c0 in my html page.
I have tried using mix-blending modes but it doesnt work as it is in the image link attached.

Any tricks?

Comment: check this question
[change text transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css), the second answer should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for. The end result works in browsers that use **webkit**, and there's a fallback for those that don't. I'm using **FF Developer Edition and Google Chrome**, and it works in both of those, however it the fallback is revealed in IE and in the regular version of FF.

Here's a link to where I've created it... http://codepen.io/fishgraphics/pen/b7eade9e3c83e8c8c173fe448f175d92

The meat of it is in CSS

```
html {
   background: #ceb691 url('http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/0f458fce470938f1695a8f9865485f17_large.jpeg') center no-repeat fixed;
}

header {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.backgroundclip h1 {
   background: url('http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/0f458fce470938f1695a8f9865485f17_large.jpeg') center no-repeat fixed;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1 {
   width: calc(100% - 60px);
   margin-top: 200px;
   font-size: 5em;
   padding: 60px 30px;
   text-align: center;
   color: orangered;
}
```

With a tiny bit utilizing Modernizr:

```
Modernizr.addTest('backgroundclip', function() {

   var div = document.createElement('div');

   if ('backgroundClip' in div.style)
      return true;

   'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.replace(/([A-Za-z]*)/g, function(val) {
      if (val + 'BackgroundClip' in div.style) return true;
   });

});
```