# How to create transparent text on non-transparent background

Tags: css

Imagine that: there is a background assigned to "body" and a white "div" with a text inside of it. And this text is so that we can see the background through it. How to implement that with CSS? Like this:[image]

Comment: Shall we have your attempt?

Comment: Could you please show some code or some example?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css)

Comment: [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) might be a good read for you :)

Comment: That's probably an image with opacity.

Comment: The text on a web browser is always its own "thing". It is not a part of its container and will not "cut out" its container when set to color: transparent or opacity: 0 in css. Therefore if the color is set to transparent or the opacity is set to 0, the text will always appear invisible. Imagine that web elements are all "solid" elements-- by setting the color to transparent you are essentially creating text using clear plastic, laying clear plastic on top of cardboard does not allow you to see what is behind the cardboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **SVG** to create a [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) with a `rect` element for the white background and a `text` element for transparent text part.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url('http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/wp-content/uploads/mountain-names.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
svg text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
svg #overlay {
  fill: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
svg #text {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

svg #r {
  fill: white;
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect id="overlay" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
      <text id="text" x="50%" y="0" dy="65px">Some text</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect id="r" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

**Update:** To create full element size overlay with transparent text you can use `position: relative` on parent element and `position: absolute` on svg and set `mask` height and width to `100%`. To center the `text` you can use `dy: 50%` with `alignment-baseline: middle;` and `text-anchor: middle;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url('http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/wp-content/uploads/mountain-names.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

svg text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

svg #overlay {
  fill: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

svg #r {
  fill: white;
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect id="overlay" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <text  id="text" x="50%" y="0" dy="50%">Some text here</text>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect id="r" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
</div>

<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use opacity;

html:

```
<body>
    <div class='frontimage'>

    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-image: url("yourimage.jpg");
}
.frontimage{
    background-image: url("yourotherimage.jpg");
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with css you can use opacity:0.6; (0 = full transparent - 1 = full visible).

```css
*{font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;}
.background{background:url(http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/paisajes-bonitos-de-oto%C3%B1o-lago.jpg);}
.text{font-size: 5em; font-weight:bold; opacity:0.6;}
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <span class="text">
   Lorem ipsum 
 </span>
</div>
```

with photoshop you can decrease the refill bar of text layer or increase transparency of this layer.
[image]