# How to make 50% transperent text in README.md file?

Tags: markdown

Mine question is how to make same text in README.md file?
[image]
Give some advices please

I expect to get semi-transperent text in mine README.md (see screenshot)
I've read this(https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#styling-text),

but there is no any solution. Maybe experienced users can help me?

Comment: I believe that is not supported natively by markdown. But as markdown renderers support html tags (in general), you should look for some html tags instead, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support text transparency. But if your markdown renderer supports HTML/CSS you can try something like this

```
<span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">Your text here</span>.
```